# Determine a Prime or composite number

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, primes

I'm writing a program to determine whether or not a given number is a prime number or a composite. My code below is what i have so far. I'm thinking that using a WHILE LOOP wouldn't be as efficient as a FOR LOOP but i may be wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int num, i;

    printf("Enter a number you want to check:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num == 1) {
        printf("%d is neither prime nor composite", num);
    }
    i = 2;
    while (i <= num - 1) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            printf("%d is composite\n\n", num);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The program works with most even numbers but when I get to, say 9 I don't get a return because it's not dividing by three. Could i add into this WHILE LOOP to compensate or would i be easier to use a FOR LOOP?

I'm thinking that if i used a FOR LOOP i could start it off sort of like this.

```
    for (i = 2, i <= num, i++) {
        num % i == 0;
    }
    printf("%d is Composite", num);
}
```

Comment: If you look carefully at your algorithm, you can detect this in fewer iterations...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have forgotten to increase the index inside your loop

```
while (i <= num-1) {
    if (num%i==0) 
    {
        printf("%d is composite\n\n",num);
        return; // test is finished
    }
    i++;   // increase i by 1
}

printf("%d is prime number\n", num); // add this line to display the prime numbers also
```

**EDIT**

I just came to see your comment about the use of `for` loop :

```
for (i = 2; i < num; i++)  // ① be careful of ; and , ② i<num not i<=num
{
    if(num % i == 0)      //  if your num is dividable ==> not prime
    {
        printf("%d is Composite", num);
        return 0;      // return from the main func
    }
}
printf("%d is prime number\n", num);   // no divisor = no return = prime number
```

**EDIT 2**

Now let's talk about efficiency :
to determine whether the number is prime or not, you can iterate for less than even half of it, how ?

if `p` is the number and `k` is its divisor then :

```
p = k * n

if ( n > sqrt(p)  && k > sqrt(p))
==> n * k > p
```

*take any pair of divisors for any integer, both the divisors cannot be greater than the square root of the integer at the same time!*

that's why you can iterate like this:

```
while (i <= sqrt(num)) {
        if (num%i==0) 
        {
            printf("%d is composite\n\n",num);
            return; // test is finished
        }
        i++;   // increase i by 1
    }
```

So for your 10000 you only iterate 100 time! and not 5000 as you thought ;)

**FURTHER**

If you're really on a tight budget, you can check only for odd numbers greater than 2 :D, I mean if it was not dividable by 2 then it'll never be dividable by 4, 6, 8 ... skip them

Example :

```
if(num%2 == 0) // check for 2
{
    printf("%d is composite\n\n",num);
    return;
}
while (i <= sqrt(num))  // check only for odd # greater than 2
{
     if (num%i==0) 
     {
         printf("%d is composite\n",num);
         return; // test is finished
     }
     i+=2;   // increase i by 2
}
printf("%d is prime\n", num);
```

Comment: okay. so i edited my code to show how i could start it off with a FOR LOOP. would my edit be correct or what am i missing? @chouaib

Comment: @Zanderg To start with, use semicolons instead of commas in the for: `for (i=2;i<=num; i++)`. You need to rethink the contents of the loop too.

Comment: You can also do `i = 1` instead of `i=2` prior to the loop, and then `while( ++i < num )`. If you're keen on simply `break`ing the loop (instead of `return`ing), you can set a small flag variable when a composite is found and do a quick `if` to determine which message to display.

Comment: so i chose to use your first example. instead of using (i <= num * .5) instead of (i <= num-1) because i figured if i were to use a large number like 100,000 than instead of going to 99,999 i only have to go to 50,000. the theory sounds right to me. What do you think @chouaib

Comment: for 100`000 you need only to iterate 316 times, and even less :) , see the update @Zanderg

Comment: oh wow...okay that really helps. Thank you for explaining these and not just giving me answers. i like to know why and how these things work so i can get a better understanding of C so I really appreciate your feedback and knowledge. @chouaib

Comment: @Zanderg : that's the purpose of SO, I'm so pleased that you got what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

Where you wrote:

```
 for (i = 2, i <= num, i++)
```

you want:

```
 for (i = 2; i < num; i++)
```

you might also think about why this:

```
 for (i = 2, i*i <= num, i++)
```

might be a big win...

Comment: This is more efficient